# My flask app doesn't return non-ascii character properly

Tags: python, utf-8, python-3.7, non-ascii-characters, flask-restful

I am trying to use flask-restful api, and as a returning value the code should returning a list of json datas. However, when contents in json is non-ascii character like (èòsèèò) the returning value

This is the a sample code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

from flask import Flask, Response
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
# Create the API
API = Api(app)



@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return Response('Here, with Response it works well: höne')

class APICLASS(Resource):
    """

    """
    def get(self, id):
        return [
        {
        "hey": 11,
        "test": "höne"
        }], 200


API.add_resource(APICLASS, '/<string:id>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But when I check the result on localhost, I see the following output:

```
[
        {
        "hey": 11,
        "test": "h\u00f6ne"
        }]
```

Comment: To be honest I didn't understand your question! I am retrieving all the data as a list of _Json_ from the database. However right before passing to _flask restful Api_ it is ok. Even, if I pass a single string like `"höne"` instead of list of _json_, I still would see the problem

Comment: I don't know how it doesn't transfer it properly. When I try to return a non-ascii character directly without any list by using the above code, I get the same error!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently, it is related to [this bug](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/issues/552).
I'm not sure if there are any side effects but this might help:

```py
# ...
app = Flask(__name__)
# Create the API
API = Api(app)

API.app.config['RESTFUL_JSON'] = {
    'ensure_ascii': False
}

@app.route('/')
# Rest of your code
```

Comment: Thanks it works. It works with just adding the last part of your code:  `api.app.config['RESTFUL_JSON'] = {
    'ensure_ascii': False`
}

Comment: Could you also tell me how can I add your code as a class, and call it in other classes? As presented in your provided link